# Can firebase messaging services can be android:exported="false"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Like to confirm if we can set `android:exported="false"` for instance id service and messaging service.

I tested by keeping `android:exported="false"` and notifications are working fine.

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 2):

The firebase-messaging library  exports an unspecialized `FirebaseMessagingService` of its own with low priority (-500). You can see it in your merged AndroidManifest.xml. This service can handle the push messages that carry notifications, like the ones you can send through the Firebase console.

If your specialized service class isn't exported, then the system will route messages from the Google services package to this unspecialized service, and notifications will work fine.

But that means you wouldn't be able to, for example, perform other actions when receiving a message or process custom data payloads.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that with any service that has at least one `intent-filter`, its `exported` value will be defaulted to `true`. [Source.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#exported)

Comment: i dont quite understand your last statement - `you wouldn't be able to, for example, perform other actions when receiving a message or process custom data payloads.` what if i want only my application to receive message and process data payload, it is alright to set the export attribute as false?

Comment: that last statement--it follows from Android delivering firebase messages to the firebase library's service *instead* of yours. if you were to write code in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` to process the data payload, it would never run. that's why the answer ought to be no, it's not alright to set the export attribute to false.

Answer (score -1):

You should export the service to be sure it is handled by your class as specified by @guest

```
<service 
    android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```