# Trying to upgrade SDK version but error "Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I'm trying to upgrade my SDK Version from 30 to 31, and add some `android:export="true"`
to my **manifest** but still got error `` Error: Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. ``

Here for my manifest

```
    <application
        android:name=".app.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".ui.SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

        <service
            android:name=".firebase.FcmServices"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

What's wrong with my codes? Is there something missing?

Comment: Yes, you can use exported="false" for you local services, but for firebase services it is not work.
Note about local service https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported. 
Duplicated issue about firebase services https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675999/can-firebase-messaging-services-can-be-androidexported-false

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works fine, and the docs show it too:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

Weird thing is that when I tested it initially, it didn't work. Only later. No idea how it's possible. Probably some bug on Android.

Anyway, this is from the docs:

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<!-- FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
      no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"             -->
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```